# Get Page ID from Backend

Tags: php, admin

How can i get a page ID from the Admin backend? I'm saving data into a metabox on a 'Page' post type, and I need to return that data on the page in another area. But $post->ID obviously dose not work... What will work? Thanks

Comment: $post->ID will always work on a post/page edit page. You might have to do 'global $post' depending on where you are using it. But it will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I needed `$_REQUEST['post']`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [this page from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Callback_args). When creating a metabox, one of the options is a callback, which when called take a paramater for `$post`, which is the same as calling `global $post` ( as a side note, you can still do this in the backend Admin and get all the same variables. )

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this plugin: http://www.primothemes.com/post/product/wp-show-ids-plugin/ is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

are you working with a custom post type for page?

You can always use `get_post_meta()` in your template to get the post type value and if its not there it doesn't matter.

** EDIT **

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you have 2 pages and you're trying to get the information in a meta box from one and load it in to the other?

If so the best way is to get set a custom field up to store a number which would be the post ID, then in the front end call it out.

The other options is to set up a custom post type with a specific meta box set up to build a list of 'Pages' then you can select from to then pull in a meta value associated with it.